# Is it possible to rely on this unofficial Python Instagram-API for web service with hundreds of users?

Tags: python, instagram-api

After successful use of this API at https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python for my own private need, I would like to give access to my script to a community through a web service with potentially hundreds of users. From your experience or knowledge of both this API and Instagram, is it possible?

For the moment, I (or we, since we are three) developped a set of scripts for internal use. We have a community around us that would be interested to use them. So, we are thinking to upscale to a real web service, but we wonder if it will be acceptable to use this API knowing it will mean hundreds of logged users from the same IP. Of course, we could use proxies, but Instagram doesn't like user with changing address (ip and location), then it would induce to dedicate one fixed IP per user... Expensive!

No code to show, but it's scripts about "growth hacking" ***staying safe*** and discovery of potential influencers in specific niches. **The question is more about the API code than about ours!**

Our current code is working perfectly since six months. It doesn't hurt Instagram and we never go above their limits, but the question is: what in the framework of a web service with a hundreds of users? Do we have to pay attention to something special or not?